# Anyway to store the first paragraph of the_content into a variable then store the remaining content into another in wordrpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the first paragraph of the content in another place on a page with the remaining content being positioned elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: This is really easy. Where are you stuck and where is your code. As it stands, your issue is a basic lack of research and effort. I believe someone would really help you if you at least try to show what you yourself has done to solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

It looks you are looking for `excerpt`.

```
 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: The excerpt simply output the first 55 words, it does not output content according to paragraphs. Maybe you should read the linked page ;-)

Comment: I can use `the_excerpt();` to show the first paragraph but i dont know how to exclude this first paragraph from the rest of `the_content();`